# How to limit content size of input box when adding content by clicking smiley icons

Tags: javascript, html

I created a input box with `maxlength="30"`

```
<div id="inputbox"><input type="text" maxlength="30" id="message" /></div>
```

I need to insert smileys into the input box by clicking smiley in smiley box,and smiely like       will be added to input box each time.

When I use `maxlength` its working fine for text content it limts the inputing charactor to 30.
But when i try to add smiley by clicking my smiley box it does not have any limit to add and its going on in each click (exceeds the max length).
Is their any method to limit the content when I try to add using clicking and adding contents.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is nothing in your question that describes the relationship between your posted HTML and this thing called a "smiley".  Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: what value are you getting in the console when you add a few smileys and then run this code: `console.log($('#message').val().length);`?

Comment: I'd love to help but I'm simply not understanding the question.  What is a "smiley box" and how is it related to the <input> element?  Do you have a jsFiddle that you can post to illustrate?

Comment: @myfunkyside . thank you for your response. When i consoled it its shows    in chrome in console window.

Comment: Add a code for checking that 'input box' has enough capacity for a smiley in the function which is invoked when smiley is clicked.  "maxlength" parameter in input tag does not specify the data size of inbut box but the size on the screen.

Comment: @Kolban I think now its easy to understand . thank you

Comment: @Fumu7. Thank you for ur response. How can i check for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this i checked the  string length inside input box when new element is added
using

```
if(($("#message").val().length) >= 30 ){
   return false;
}else{
   //do the operation
}
```

this worked fine for me.